How do we control the base voltage of a PNP transistor?
How can I calculate the base voltage and base current of this transistor for any value of R1 and R2?


Unfortunately you are asserting things that are incorrect. This makes it really difficult to answer any residual question you have because anyone answering would have to undo all of your false assertions and retrain you to think along proper lines. Maybe you should just stick to asking a simple question rather than saying some of the things in your question.

Is this school work / homework?

It was not a school assignment. Normally I was using an LDR instead of resistor R1 and a 100k resistor instead of resistor R2. It was a simple darkness sensor DIY circuit. https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-LDR-Darkness-Sensor-Circuit-Simple-DIY/

@SerkanKaya, with 100 kohm at R2 (and an appropriate LDR to balance it at R1) you probably want a Darlington (or possibly a p-channel MOSFET) in place of Q1, not BC557.

@The Photon, Thank you for your advice. It really got better with Darlington.

First off, this type of a switch (common emitter) is controlled by the base current, not voltage. Base-emitter voltage is more or less constant, typically assumed to be 0.7V (-0.7V for a PNP) in forward bias, same as a diode. With a transistor you first meet that forward voltage, then you start feeding current to turn it on.
How much current? Let's start with a look at the load side. Your diagram shows 560 ohms in series with a red LED. Red LEDs have a forward voltage (Vf) of about 1.8V. If we were to tie the load resistor directly to 9V, we will have up to 7.2V across it. That tells us we'd get at most 12.8mA of current.
Let's make an assumption that because we’re building a switch, we wish to to drive the transistor hard enough to be in saturation with a collector current (Ic) of greater than, say, 12.5mA. We'll get into how to do that that in a bit.
As I mentioned up top, and you may know, base voltage (Vbe) in forward bias is often assumed to be a one diode-drop of 0.7V (-0.7V for a PNP.) That's a good first estimate.
But... you asked how to calculate the base voltage and current. The answer is, it depends. For our purposes here, just know that the forward-bias Vbe is influenced by collector current (Ic) and temperature. For a silicon device, forward-bias Vbe could be anywhere in a range of 550-800mV, depending on these factors.
In fact, to compute your actual Vbe you'll need to use the Shockley equation, or perhaps use a simulator that does that heavy lifting for you (Spoiler alert: I used a Falstad sim to get an estimate.) Sometimes the data sheet will have a Vbe vs. Ic curve available.
More about computing Vbe here: Finding the Real \$V_{BE}\$
We have kind of an idea already for this transistor. Ic being only at 12.5mA is pretty light, so we know that Vbe will come in lower than 0.7V. A quick sim at that current shows about 0.66V at room temp. (See below, later.)
Do we really care about exact Vbe?
Remember, we're building a switch, not a controlled current source. We want to saturate the transistor. What does that mean? It means that we're driving the base with significantly more current than is needed, in order to make the collector-emitter voltage be very small. The benefit? Its power dissipation is minimized, and we can bury any Vbe and DC current gain variation with a surplus of drive.
For example, if the transistor has a stated DC current gain (hFE) of 100, to get Ic = 12.5mA we'd need to drive at least 0.125mA to the base. This transistor would be biased on the edge of its 'active' region, but not yet saturated. The circuit current gain, \$\beta\$, is 100, same as hFE. The problem is, hFE can change a lot, so a transistor that has an hFE < 100 would not saturate, and even worse, would not deliver our target current. Not what you want in a switch.
(hFE is the transistor's intrinsic DC gain, as seen on a tester. \$\beta\$ is the gain realized in a circuit.)
What's a reasonable saturation base current for this device? How about 4x the 0.125 mA base current needed to get 12.5mA at the collector, or Ib = 0.5 mA, making circuit \$\beta\$ = 25.
Some designers would go even harder and use Ib = 1.25mA for \$\beta\$ = 10. I think that's unnecessary here but I'll touch on it anyway.
We now have enough information to compute R2 by itself, assuming no R1 (not to worry, we'll come back to it.)
We will set 0.5 mA at the base. Now, find R2:

R2 = (9V - 0.66V)/0.5mA = about 16.7k to GND for \$\beta\$ = 25

or, more conservatively:

R2 = (9V - 0.66V)/1.25mA = about 6.67k to GND for \$\beta\$ = 10

Your PNP will be fully 'on'; you will get your target current.

How to Calculate R1 and R2
So far we've focused on R2, which sets base current to GND.
Say you need R1 for some reason (we'll need it for your LDR circuit, which we'll discuss below.) How to set R1 and R2?
Basically, you pick some (reasonable) value for R1, then use Kirchhoff's Current Law to determine the current needed in R2 for a target base current Ib.
That is:

I(R1) + Ib + I(R2) = 0

or:

I(R2) = -(Ib + I(R1)) = -(Ib + Vbe/R1)

Say we chose 50k as R1, and want to drive Ib with 0.5mA.
Then:

I(R2) = -(0.5mA + 0.66V/50k) = -0.513mA

Solving for R2:

R2 = (9V - Vbe)/I(R2)
R2 = (9V - 0.66V)/0.513mA = 16.2k

Any R2 value 16.2k and below will ensure that we have at least 0.5mA of base drive, enough to be in saturation.

Making this work with a Light-Dependent Resistor (LDR)
You state in the comments that you  want to replace R2 with an LDR, similar to here: https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-LDR-Darkness-Sensor-Circuit-Simple-DIY/.
I'll note that the Instructables design is for a 'walk light' that turns off the LED when light is present. What you show in your schematic is that the LED will turn on when there is light.
With that out of the way, let's dive in.
First, note that LDR resistance varies from 1-2M ohm (dark) to 100s or 10s of k ohm (light). We know from our work above that we need R2 to be about 16k ohm to GND to achieve saturation turn-on. That's in the ballpark for some LDRs, but not for the one shown in the Instructables design. We'll come back to this.
We can just use the LDR in place for R2. But, adding R1 sets a minimum light threshold to start turning on the LED, otherwise in the dark it will be fully off.
As a starting point, the Instructables link shows 50k. That's reasonable. With 50k, if LDR dark resistance is greater than 700k ohm, there will be no or almost no LED illumination since Vbe will be below 0.6V.
As light increases and LDR resistance goes below 700k, the 50k will be pulled down below 0.55V or so. Vbe will begin to go into forward-active bias region. Once Vbe reaches 0.66V, we're sinking 0.125 mA plus the 50k current, and Vbe will hold there. The LED will be fully on if hFE is 100.
As you add even more light, the LDR will start sinking more and more from PNP base. If there's enough light for the LDR to reach 16k or so, the transistor will reach our target saturation and the LED will be fully illuminated.
However, there's trouble brewing. The LDR linked in the Instructables states that it is 50-100k ohms at 10 lux. This won’t turn on the LED fully, at least at those light levels. In fact, with this LDR at 100k you'll only get about 7 mA at the LED. The transistor will still be in the linear region, not saturated.
We can improve matters by adding a second transistor in a Darlington configuration. The transistor current gains basically multiply, so with hFE's of 100 each we have an overall gain of 10,200.
That is,

hFE (Darlington pair) = (hFE1 + (hFE1 x hFE2) + hFE2)

With this much gain we will switch the LED fully on at even very low light levels.
Here's a simulation you can try with a single PNP as you propose (on left) compared to an improved one with Darlington drive (on right) (simulate it here):

Not only does the Darlington version light the LED fully, it has a much sharper light response. Its minimum sensitivity will also be easier to adjust.

In general, I agree to the above approach. However, two short comments: (1) The BJT is a voltage-controlled device. Hence, we do NOT "control the base current". The relatively large base current is the RESULT of saturation - not its cause  (remember: In saturation also the base-collector np junction is forward biased). However, for calculation purposes we may use the current-controlled model. (2) It does not help too much to " check the Vbe vs. Ic curve" because this characteristic is extremely temperature dependent and, hence, is not a suitable tool for such calculations.

(1) Underlying physics aside, BJTs are controlled by current and specified and modeled as such. Vbe has a tempco of about 2mV/deg.C, yes. But Vbe is much more heavily influenced by Ic, although still in the 600-800mV range. I mention this as OP wants to know how to set the 'voltage' (i.e., current) accurately, so they should understand the influence of Ic on Vbe.

By the way, a quick sim for an hFE=100 PNP in this config shows Vbe = 660mV.

BTW, in the left schematic, the 100K resistor (reference designators - !) is way too large.  A transistor with a beta of 100 will not saturate.  Round numbers, the LED wants 12 mA and the transistor can source only 8.

@AnalogKid That's absolutely correct. A relatively crappy CdS sensor (100k ohm at 10 lux, say) won't sink enough current to do the job. That’s exactly why a Darlington setup is more appropriate.

And yet, the schematic still is up.

Intentionally, to illustrate the issue. The choice to make the slider be 100k min reflects the LDR spec that OP refers to. There are better ones, but if OP wants to use this one, a Darlington setup would be better.

I'm really grateful for your response. It made me realize many things I didn't know about how transistors work.

@hacktastical - Hi, I appreciate you want to make the answer perfect but... (a) you're about to trigger alarms due to the number of edits, and (b) do you know that every edit bumps the topic to the top of the site homepage active list, even when the edit is small, and all that bumping (especially, but not only, multiple times in an hour) gets noticed - and not in a good way. || I don't know if you have zero or one more edits possible before we start getting alarms (i.e. I don't remember whether it's 20 or more than 20 edits that triggers it). Can you pause the edits? TY

The straightforward way is to use a Thevenin transformation. Say R1 is 100 ohms and R2 is 800 ohms. Then you can use the Thevenin transformation to redraw your circuit as

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
From this schematic you should be able to see that even though the Thevenin equivalent voltage is more than 0.7 V below the main supply voltage, the base current is limited by the Thevenin resistance.
So even though the divider, if it weren't loaded, would produce a voltage below 8.3 V, you still won't draw extreme currents from the transistor base because the divider, as a source, has non-zero equivalent series resistance.
Since your goal when designing this circuit is to obtain a certain base current to ensure the transistor is fully saturated, you have some freedom in choosing the resistors --- you could either pick higher value resistors with a lower R2/R1 ratio, or lower values with a higher R2/R1 ratio, and get the same base current.
To make a final choice you need some additional constraint, for example that you should minimize overall power consumption, or that you must allow for a certain amount of variation of the Q1 b-e junction voltage. (Optimizing for power consumption will probably lead you to choose R1 as an open circuit and R2 at whatever value gives your desired base current).

I have to admit that it is really not clear to me how the Thevenin transformation - as shown above - can help to find suitable values for R1 and R2. Remember: The question was "How can I calculate the base voltage and base current of this transistor for any value of R1 and R2?"

Agree.  The diode (Q1 base-emitter junction) across R1 essentially isolates R1 and R2 from each other.  This violates the definition of a Thevenin transform.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem

@LvW Step 1: Figure out what Thevenin voltage and resistance you want. (determined by the desired base current, tolerance for component variation, and any power consumption requirements) Step 2: Choose the resistors to give those values.

@AnalogKid, The combination of V1, R1, and R2 has a Thevenin equivalent that does not depend on how this network is loaded. That's exactly the point of the Thevenin transformation --- the equivalent circuit can be determined without knowing what load will be connected.

@LvW the other value of this answer is that by re-drawing the circuit with the Thevenin transformation, OP can see why having the "divider output voltage" below 8.3 V doesn't cause extreme currents through the transistor base (as their initial post indicated they were concerned about)

The following applies to BJT-based amplifier applications only:
We have no other chance - we have to calculate/determine the required base voltage Vb using such a voltage divider.
I understand that your doubts are the result of some uncertainties connected with (a) the current into the base (very large tolerances) and (b) the strong temperature sensitivities of the relevant Ic=f(Vbe) relationship (Shockleys equation).
However, there is a method to compensate (up to a certain degree) these uncertainties: NEGATIVE FEEDBACK.
For this reason, all good working transistor-based amplification stages contain an emitter resistor Re which (a) determines the DC emitter voltage Ve and (b) thereby provides current-controlled voltage feedback:
Any unwanted change in (resp. deviation from) the desired collector current Ic acts back in a corresponding change in Ve resp Vbe. For a good working feedback, the base voltage Vb - created by the base voltage divider - should be as stiff as possible (principle of a low resistive voltage source Vb). For calculation of the two resistors (as low as allowed) the DC base current should be considered (even if it is known with large uncertainties only).
Comment: There is another method for biasing the transistor with negative DC feedback (one single resistor between collector and base). However, this alternative works not as good as the method as desribed above (Re-feedback).

This is not an amplifier application, so your first sentence is telling us that the rest of your answer does not relate to the question asked.

@ The photon How do you know? In the question I cannot find any information about the operating mode (saturation or linear operation).

in a comment on AnalogKid's answer, OP says "I want the transistor to behave like a saturated switch." And in a comment on the question post they say "It was a simple darkness sensor DIY circuit." (Admittedly my answer doesn't address the aspect of one resistor being an LDR either)

This answer changed as more information became available, and has been cleaned up.
In accordance with the first rule of forum-ing, here is the answer the question in the title:

How do we control the base voltage of a PNP transistor?

In your circuit, we don't.  OK, that was easy.
Because the Q1 emitter is connected directly to the battery, the base voltage is independent of all of the resistors in the schematic.  It is one diode drop (the Q1 Vbe) below the battery voltage.
Begin with Vbe - the transistor base-emitter junction forward voltage.  That sets the voltage across R1 and R2, which sets their currents.
Update2:
Based on additional information in the comments, here is a quickie design process for approximate values.  In this process, the three resistors are essentially independent.  Of importance is that the Q1 base-emitter junction is a voltage clamp across R1.  Within reason, the voltage across R1 always is 0.6 V, and the voltage across R2 always is 9.4 V.  This makes calculating them pretty easy.
First, pick an LED with a known forward voltage Vf, and an operating current Iled.  Assume that Q1's Vcesat is 0.1 V.
R3 = (V1 - Q1 Vcesat - D1 Vf) / Iled.  Adjust R3 for the closest available standard value.
Set the Q1 base current to 1/10th of its collector current.  This 10:1 ratio is a carryover from a 1950's rule of thumb.  With many small-signal transistors today, this can be relaxed to 15:1 or even 20:1.  The higher ratios will increase the Q1 saturation voltage, but that is not a problem in this circuit.
Assume the Q1 Vbe is 0.6 V
R2 = (V1 - Vbe) / (Iled / 10)
Because the voltage across R2 is fixed, its value does not affect R1
R1's only job is to assure a fast and complete turn-off of Q1 when power is disconnected from the circuit.  Because the current through R2 is fixed, the value of R1 does not change the voltage across it; that is clamped at Vbe.  The value of R1 does change how much of the R2 current goes through Q1 and how much of it comes through R1.  As long as R1 is more than 10x R2, its value has minimal effect on the circuit operation.
And to be clear, a Thevenin transformation does not apply here.  In fact, it cannot apply here.  Thevenin equivalence is a specific tool for a limited range of situations.  It is great for steady-state network puzzles and calculating the resistor value for active termination of a signal trace, but it works only with resistors; no capacitors, inductors, or (importantly) diodes.  Note the very first sentence here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem

I think this answer probably should have been a comment. Maybe delete it for now, ask for the clarification in a comment, and when you get the clarification edit the answer and undelete it?

Presumably the goal is to have Q1 in saturation so that R3 controls the LED current.

Thank you for answering. I want the transistor to behave like a saturated switch. I wanted to know how to find the resistors R1 and R2 necessary for the transistor to behave in this way.

It was not a school assignment. Normally I was using an LDR instead of resistor R1 and a 100k resistor instead of resistor R2. It was a simple darkness sensor DIY circuit. Because I was curious about this part of the circuit, I organized it this way and asked.

The first part of the answer has been cleaned up, and I added a direct response to the question in the title.
