A circuit to dim an LED whenever it gets dark
I want to make a circuit to automatically control the brightness of an LED.
I want the LED to be at its brightest when it is brightest outside, and to start dimming as it becomes dark outside.
I was thinking of using an LDR in series with an LED (a green 5mm LED THT), as shown below:

Or is it better to rather use the LDR to bias the base of an NPN, as shown below:

Does anyone else have a better way to do this?
Which of the two ways is better?

Have you tried it or simulated it? What have you found?

Both should work. The second design is strongly Beta dependent so you need to match Ldr resistance vs. Beta.

what does better mean?

We can also use an LED as a photodiode and sense and drive it directly from a current limited LM358. The two need to be isolated.

@D.A.S. can you provide a circuit on this?

@JoeyB LDRs have a non-linear behavior with expect to irradiance. Human brightness sensations in brighter conditions are based solely on one and only one of our cone cells. (The rod cells are saturated.) The response is logarithmic to irradiance. Photodiodes and LEDs used as photodiodes are linear. Have you worked out how to map the chosen sensor response to the desired LED current, yet? You could just shoot from the hip. But sometimes it is worth a moment to consider details.

@periblepsis I have not mapped it out, I am just looking for the LED to dimmer at night since I do not want to be staring at a bright LED at night, but I still want to see if the LED is on during the day. So I see the two options are LDR and photodiodes.

@JoeyB Okay. Just asking. Usually, the quality of the results depend upon how well the details are examined. I was just suggesting putting some thought into this. That's all. Shooting from the hip may be fine. I can't say. I just tend to go for the theoretical details first and try to get myself into the right ballpark.

Do you want to compress 3 decades of Lux to 1.5 decades of LED current for more useful output?  do you want it cut out at dark, then add a shunt resistor

@D.A.S. is it hard to understand what you are trying to ask without the circuit you posted in your comment

Neither is very good. I offer a couple of options here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/727883/how-do-we-control-the-base-voltage-of-a-pnp-transistor/727945#727945

The issue with both of your proposals is that LDR 'on' resistance can still be pretty high. A common one is 50~100k at 10 lux.
Given that high resistance, and the fact that it varies a lot, it's not not feasable to just connect the LED in series with it. Even using a single NPN to boost the current isn't quite enough since you will be at the mercy of both the LDR's resistance the transistor's current gain (hFE) which might not be enough to give full drive to your LED.
A better approach is to use two transistors in Darlington configuration. As below (simulate it here)

I've modeled the LDR with a 1M pot and 95k series resistance. The Darlington provides a current gain of over 10,000. As the LDR resistance decreases, the LED will come on sharply when the first NPN base is at least two Vbe thresholds (about 1V).
You can tune this to your specific LDR by adjusting the lower resistor. If for example your LDR is 10k at 10 lux, you'd change the lower resistor to 5k or so.

Very nice post in your previous post answer. Any more edits for this one... Just pulling your leg.

Your design is common-emitter, which tends to act as like an on/off switch, unless base potential & current is set very precisely. This is called "biasing", which your design fails to do, and is not easy to fix without knowing a lot more about the LDR.
The design below employs the transistor in an emitter-follower configuration. It differs in that it requires no biasing at all, and the response is almost completely linear, rather than on/off:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this arrangement, emmiter potential \$V_E\$ "follows" the base \$V_B\$, but just a little lower:
$$ V_E = V_B - 0.7V $$
The resistor potential divider formed by LDR1 and R1 cause \$V_B\$ to vary with light level, and you would choose R1 to produce a change between about +11V at B in the light, and closer to zero in the dark. That would produce a similar voltage variation at E, to power the LED.
The transistor's base draws very little current via the LDR, allowing LDR1 and R1 to behave as a voltage divider, without being concerned with heavy loading by the LED, a problem present in your first (top) circuit. Current for the LED is drawn directly from the supply instead, via the transistor's collector.

Thanks for drawing my schematic.


Does anyone else have a better way to do this?

Yes.
Your second schematic shows the transistor acting as a saturated switch.  This type of circuit will have a very small ambient light brightness range between the LED being full on and full off.
A better way is to move the LED and its resistor to the emitter, connecting the collector directly to the 12 V.  Now the transistor is acting as an emitter follower, a linear circuit.
You show the transistor being "dangle-biased" by the lone LDR.  This is possible, but very finicky, with the transistor bias current changing with temperature.  A better way is to leave the LDR where it is and add a resistor from the base to GND so it and the LDR form a voltage divider.  With the correct resistor values you should get something close to what you want.
Now the tricky part is getting an LDR with the "right" resistance range.  Do you already have one?

Why would the current setup not be considered "linear"? When you say linear what two linearly proportional values, to the voltage and current?

Getting a bunch (about 20 next week to test) :). The company I purchased it from does not have a datasheet just a mechanical drawing datasheet :(

I see some opportunities that you may consider;

Define your limits of sensor and LED current for voltage, resistance or current by experiment.
Your circuit will never create a predictable midpoint of currents with an unknown sensor output. After calibration, define the twilight sensor levels. PD's are far more accurate and linear than LDR's.   e.g. 0.5 uA/uW = mA/mW of light but with a wavelength curve.   Regardless of linear, quadratic or inverse quadratic sensor, you must define worst case sensor and LED currents and tolerances expect from both.

Choose a more common, efficient 5V instead of 12V to permit lower heat loss and a brighter LED than 10 mA shown in schematic 10V/1k. But consider 10% min. for low current as a safe guideline to prevent electromigration aging.(opinion)

Eliminate LED glare by avoiding direct exposure and spread it on the wall. Then leave it running at max current using 5V.

Consider red LEDs. They use them in darkrooms and sub.'s at night.

Control the LED light AND sensor crosstalk so that it does cause positive feedback to the sensor (photoresistor(LDR) or photodiode (PD)) and stay on.

You can reduce LED to PD crosstalk by using an semiconductor-filter such as a GaN blue clear LED which is possible as longer wavelength light detected is attenuated. But do not use white LEDs as detectors as the phosphors will attenuate too much. ( This is why diodes are encapsulated in epoxy as the glass diodes created leakage current)

You can use a comparator with open drain or collector NPN output to pull down  high current and a resistor to pull down the dim current level for a bi-level approach at the threshold of sunset or sunrise.


